# No field of characteristic $p > 0$ contains a primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots-of-unity

> No field of characteristic $p > 0$ contains a primitive $p^{th}$ root of unity.

I spent the whole day yesterday on this problem, still no progress!

I reworded the question and came up with this,

> If $F$ is a field of characteristic $p$, then $g(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+1$  is irreducible $\forall x \in F$.

Clearly, $1$ is a root, but I guess it has to be different from $1$.

I tried using this $$x^p-1 = (x-1)(x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+1)$$

If $F$ does not have a $p^{th}$ root of unity then $g(x)=x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+1$ is irreducible in $F$ so if I adjoin root $\alpha$ of $g$ to $F$ then $[F(\alpha):F]=p-1$.

Not sure if this leads to something.

I also used freshman's dream to get
$$f = x^p - 1 = x^p-1^p=(x-1)^p.$$

So any factors of $f$ have to have the form $(x-1)^k $, $1 \leq k \leq p$,
but still nothing, any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost got it. If $x^p-1=(x-1)^p=0$ then $x=1$ because fields are integral domains.

Comment: The OP is missing a long time from M.SE, but you can add few words to your answer showing how many mistakes he made. For instance, how could be a polynomial like $g$ irreducible if it has a root in $F$? (Not mentioning the unfortunate statement "irreducible $\forall x\in F$.) Reading the question and the answer an user can hardly figure out why a field of characteristic $p>0$ does not contain a primitive $p$th root of unity.